# What's the best way to build a sparse MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, database-design

I'm building a big table, for statistic purposes, where I have a lot of different attributes with (in some cases) a lot of different values. I was wondering what is the best way of building such table.

The table will be like this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d2793):

```
create table T (
    id    INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    colA  INT(11),
    colB  VARCHAR(32),
    colC  VARCHAR(10),
    colD  VARCHAR(10),
    colE  INT(2),
    colF  VARCHAR(10),
    colG  TINYINT,
    colH  TINYINT,
    colI  TINYINT,
    colJ  INT(4),
    UNIQUE(colA,colB,colC,colD,colE,colF,colG,colH,colI)
);
```

All the columns except the last one are possible filters for this column (like "all rows that have colB = 'a', colD = 'c' and colG != 1"), and all have the same probability of being used as filter. Cardinality for those columns range from 18 to 2.

Combinations of values for columns from A to F have the same probability to occur, while columns G, H and I are related to certain values of column B and have the following probabilities:

```
 col | val |   %  |   col | val |   %  |   col | val |   %  |
-----|-----|------|  -----|-----|------|  -----|-----|------|
colG |  0  | 77.0 |  colH |  0  | 93.3 |  colI |  0  | 99.1 |
-----|-----|------|  -----|-----|------|  -----|-----|------|
colG |  1  |  5.8 |  colH |  1  |  1.5 |  colI |  1  |  0.9 |
-----|-----|------|  -----|-----|------|
colG |  2  |  7.4 |  colH |  2  |  1.6 |
-----|-----|------|  -----|-----|------|
colG |  3  |  9.8 |  colH |  3  |  3.6 |
```

I thought of building the table horizontally but it would have had too many columns, so I went for this 'vertical' design, but taking into account the cardinalities I found it can potentially have about 20M+ rows at some point, and at the moment we cannot partition the tables in any way. So probably a mixed approach (vertical design for most attributes, some values as columns), or maybe use some auxiliary table (I thought about using a table for combinations of cols G, H and I).

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["horizontal" vs. "vertical" table design, SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256830/horizontal-vs-vertical-table-design-sql)